# Sorting in JavaScript by index size

Tags: javascript

How to sort a string with its index size?

Help with the method of sorting or without any method ?

Eg:

```
Input : sky is blue today
Output: is sky blue today
```

Comment: You want to sort by the length of each word?

Comment: looks like an assignment. what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You want to sort by the length of each word?

```js
var str = "sky is blue today"

console.log(
  str.split(" ").sort(function(a, b) { return a.length - b.length; }).join(" ")
)
```

Comment: I missed it by whisker. + 1 for one liner.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const toSort = 'sky is blue today';

const sorted = toSort.split(' ').sort((a,b) => a.length < b.length ? -1: 1).join(' ');

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```js
var arr = "sky is blue today";

var result  = arr.split(' ').sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length).join(' ');
console.log(result);
```

Description

> `split(' ')` : To split sentence into array of words   delimiter
>
> `Sort(<function>)` : To Sort array by length of word
>
> `Join(" ")` : Again join array by adding " " after each word

[**Note: =>(Arrow functionality is not supported by IE)** .](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: I beat you to it

Comment: "I beat you to it" expression meaning "I was quicker than you"

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/beat-someone-to-it

Comment: but not running in all browsers like mine - I can remove whitespace too